# Ошибка ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage при отправке Firebase приложения в TestFlight

Tags: ios, cordova

В своем приложении для iOS использую Google Firebase. При загрузке билда в TestFlight получил предупреждение от Apple:

> ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - Apple will stop accepting submissions of apps that use UIWebView APIs . See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview for more information.

Просмотрел весь stackoverflowи русский и англоязычный, но все предлагаемые меры мне не подошли. Активно общаюсь с саппортом и Google и Apple.

Pod-сы Firebase обновлены (это проверили в саппорте Google).

```
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Firebase/Storage', '~> 4.0'
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
pod 'Fabric'
pod 'Crashlytics'
```

Для обнаружения остатков UIWebView в приложении воспользовался командой в терминале `grep -r "UIWebView" .` (по совету https://stackoverflow.com/a/57729472/10348010). Получил результат и отправил его в саппорт Apple, от них пришел вот такой ответ:

> I’ve examined the output and see two references to UIWebView in there, both relating to Cordova. It appears that one of the Cordova plug-ins that you are using is using a UIWebView, specifically cordova-plugin-browsertab. Unfortunately you’re going to have to contact them to find out how to get an updated version of the plug-in, or what else they recommend that you do.

Что мне делать с этими плагинами Cordova? Не могу понять откуда они воообще взялись.

Answer (score 0):

Плагин cordova-plugin-browsertab больше не поддерживается. Вам нужно найти альтернативу или пересмотреть подход к реализации задачи.

Посмотрев вопросы в репозитории cordova-plugin-browsertab я нашел это - [cordova-plugin-safariviewcontroller](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-safariviewcontroller)

Так же проверьте, что вы используете cordova-ios@5.1 или выше.

Избегайте плагины которые не поддерживаются или давно не обновлялись, так как Apple полностью переходит с UIWebKit на WKWebKit.

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий. Ноя не могу понять откуда Cordova вообще взялась в проекте? Ничего из их программ или плагинов не использую, использую только Xcode и Firebase! Вот в чем загвоздка

Comment: @StanislavPutilov У вас гибридное мобильное приложение? Или вы все делаете в XCode?

Comment: использую только Xcode. Не скажете как мне проверить есть ли в действительно плагин от Cordova и что он конкретно делает в моем приложении? Голова идет кругом

Comment: @StanislavPutilov Cordova хранит свои плагины в папке plugins. Проверьте есть ли у Вас такая папка и содержится ли там что-то. Второй вариант это поиск по проекту по ключевому слову cordova